# "Entity type has no key defined" exception

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am working to let the About function in the page to show Enrollment Date for each student, but I am getting this error:

[image]

Comment: The error is self explanatory. You are missing primary key in students entity. Can you paste you student entity class

Comment: I did the DB first on SQL not inside Visual Studio, so what actually I did is from the Model I click in EF designer from DB, then I got same DB from SQL. I assigned a primary key for student anyway. Thanks for your trying to help

Comment: If you have a key defined in your model this error does not make sense.

Comment: In Model I have only the diagram for the DB should I add something into it?

Comment: You can out your cursor on Student type and see its definition. I am interested to see how EF generated that class for you. And you also if you could paste the error message as text not image that will be great too

Comment: UW.DAL.Student: : EntityType 'Student' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.

Students: EntityType: EntitySet 'Students' is based on type 'Student' that has no keys defined.

Comment: I pasted the text error, from where could I add the key for student?

Comment: If you take a look at student type you should see [Key] on top your primary key column

Comment: I told you I did that already in SQL server.

Comment: Yes you did. Then it might EF generation error. That's why I want to verify your student entity object. Just copy its content and simple paste with your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entity Framework distinguish different objects in it's context by their keys. the problem is that the `Student` entity does not have any key defined. if you are using code first maybe you are not following any conventions
conventions for primary key is like this

```
public int EntityNameID {get;set;}
```

or

```
public int Id {get;set;}
```

> Code First infers that a property is a primary key if a property on a
>   class is named “ID” (not case sensitive), or the class name followed
>   by "ID". If the type of the primary key property is numeric or GUID it
>   will be configured as an identity column.

you can also assign `[Key][1]` attribute to the property you want to be the key of your entity.

another way is to define the key of your entity using fluent API.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Student>.HasKey(s => s.Id);
```

Comment: (Addition) If it doesn't follow this rule you can decorate the property with the attribute [Key].

Comment: I am using DB first from SQL server how can I fix it using your suggestion?

Comment: you should modify your database and define a primary key for your table  @wadbarca

Comment: I have already defined the SID as primary key in student table.

Comment: please add codes related to your student entity to question